# How to pass on variable names (i.e. var_x) OR transformation of variables (i.e. as.factor(var_x)) in same function?

Tags: r, function, transform

In ggplot we can easily put in variable names of dataframes in our code, i.e.

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b= 1:10, c= 1:10)
ggplot(df, aes(a, b, col= c)) + geom_point()
```

or we can transform the variables right inside the code, i.e. here we change the colour variable `c` to a factor:

```
ggplot(df, aes(a, b, col= as.factor(c))) + geom_point()
```

I want my function to do the same. So if my function is

```
my_fun <- function(data, var){
  var <- deparse(substitute(var))
  class(data[ , var])
}
```

I want `my_fun(df, a)` to return `numeric` and, on the other hand, `my_fun(df, as.factor(a))` must return `factor`. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of these.

```
my_fun1 <- function(data, x) eval(substitute(x), data)

my_fun2 <- function(data, ...) with(data, ...)

my_fun3 <- with
```

e.g. (and similarly for the others)

```
my_fun1(BOD, Time) # returns numeric object
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 7

my_fun1(BOD, factor(Time))  # returns factor object
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 7
## Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 7
```