# How to find object name passed to function

Tags: r, function, object

I have a function which takes a dataframe and its columns and processes it in various ways (left out for simplicity). We can put in column names as arguments or transform columns directly inside function arguments (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69915317/how-to-pass-on-variable-names-i-e-var-x-or-transformation-of-variables-i-e)). I need to find out what object(s) are passed in the function.

Reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(x= 1:10, y=1:10)

myfun <- function(data, col){
col_new <- eval(substitute(col), data)
# magic part
object_name <- ...
# magic part
plot(col_new, main= object_name)
}
```

For instance, the expected output for `myfun(data= df, x*x)` is the plot `plot(df$x*df$x, main= "x")`. So the title is `x`, not `x*x`.  What I have got so far is this:

```
myfun <- function(data, col){
colname <- tryCatch({eval(substitute(col))}, error= function(e) {geterrmessage()})
colname <- gsub("' not found", "", gsub("object '", "", colname))
plot(eval(substitute(col), data), main= colname)
    }
```

This function gives the expected output but there must be some more elegant way to find out to which object the input refers to. The answer must be with base R.

Comment: What do you want returned? "x" as a string? as a symbol?

Comment: @Adam As a string. The second function returns the expected output.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substitute to get the expression passed as col and then use eval and all.vars to get the values and name.

```
myfun <- function(data, col){
  s <- substitute(col)
  plot(eval(s, data), main = all.vars(s), type = "o", ylab = "")
}
myfun(df, x * x)
```

Anothehr possibility is to pass a one-sided formula.

```
myfun2 <- function(formula, data){
  plot(eval(formula[[2]], data), main = all.vars(formula), type = "o", ylab = "")
}
myfun2(~ x * x, df)
```

Comment: Awesome! The magic part is all.vars()! Using myfun(df, x*x) for the reproducible example in the question gives the expected output now.

Answer (score 0):

The `rlang` package can be very powerful when you get a hang of it. Does something like this do what you want?

```r
library(rlang)

myfun <- function (data, col){
  .col <- enexpr(col)
  
  unname(sapply(call_args(.col), as_string))
}
```

This gives you back the "wt" column.

```r
myfun(mtcars, as.factor(wt))    
# [1] "wt"
```

I am not sure your use case, but this would work for multiple inputs.

```r
myfun(mtcars, sum(x, y))
# [1] "x" "y"
```

And finally, it is possible you might not even need to do this, but rather store the expression and operate directly on the data. The tidyeval framework can help with that as well.

Comment: Can we do this in R base? See edited question.

Comment: @machine Yes probably but I never do and am less familiar. Hopefully somebody else can answer for that.

Comment: +1 anyway, thanks! I want base R because I am working on a package and want no unnecessary packages being included.

Comment: I got you. I will say, `rlang` is everywhere so it wouldn't be a huge barrier as a dependency. I do the same, but try to avoid more obscure and less common packages. Except for those using R in a highly restricted setting, basically everybody will have `rlang` installed. Things to consider. Packages are a huge part of the R ecosystem. Depending on too many of them bloats your own package, but I am not sure using none is the right answer either.